# The actual ec2 instance does not get the iam instance profile that Elastic Beanstalk creates and says the environment has. How do make this happen?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using boto3 to create Elastic Beanstalk applications and environments remotely. I want one of these environments to call other AWS services using boto3. My understanding is that Elastic Beanstalk "creates a default instance profile, called `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`, and assigns managed policies with default permissions to it." (from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html)

That page also states "An instance profile is a container for an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role that you can use to pass role information to an Amazon EC2 instance when the instance starts."

When I inspect the Elastic Beanstalk Environment's configuration on the web console I see `IAM instance profile: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` under the Security heading.

However, my instance cannot call boto3 functions without an error `botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`.

When I inspect the ec2 instance on the console I see nothing under IAM role. If I set the IAM role from here the instance is then able to call boto3 functions.

How do I go about getting the ec2 instance to automatically inherit the IAM role .. or how do I specify that role to be set or indeed another custom role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take a look the boto3 "[create_environment()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html#ElasticBeanstalk.Client.create_environment)" function definition, we have an  option to specify "optionSettings"

```
OptionSettings=[
    {
        'ResourceName': 'string',
        'Namespace': 'string',
        'OptionName': 'string',
        'Value': 'string'
    },
]
```

We can use this to explicitly specify the IAM instance profile to be attached to the EC2 instances launched as a part of your Beanstalk environment.

The Option setting to use would be "[aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalinglaunchconfiguration)", option name : IamInstanceProfile, who's default value is "NONE". Specify the Instance profile name or ARN for value.

Answer (score 0):

You get the instance profile from the metadata: `curl -s 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info`

Comment: I don't have a problem identifying the instance profile really. I don't know how to make sure the ec2 instance actually inherits the the profile or how to explicitly set it programmatically when setting up the Elastic beanstalk environment.